# Ajax call is not working with asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below is my Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetCities", "People")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {'id' : id },
    success: function (cities) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error:function(err, result){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

& this is my action method.

```
    public ActionResult GetCities(int id)
    {
        var cities = StateDB.GetCities().Where(c => c.StateId == id);
        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When i try to access this using `http://localhost/People/GetCities/2`, it works, 
but it is not working with above ajax call.
It gives me 404 'Not found' error.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You should remove the `contentType` option and use `data: { id: id }`. Are you using areas in your app?

Comment: If possible show the route config too.

Comment: Does your Web API have the `/api` prefix?

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("GetCities", "People")/' + id` and remove `data:{...}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : id is a javascript variable. & it is not a web api.  Route is default one:              routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @smokingkills, Yes I know. Your specifying `contentType: 'json'`, but your not stringifying the data

Comment: @GeneR:that didn't work

Comment: check with F12(developer tools) your request and query string.

Comment: that's weird. the url shows http://localhost/people/@Url.Action. What might be the cause

Comment: is your ajax code located in .js file? javascript files are not parsed by asp.net mvc

Comment: You obviously have this in an external js file. Razor code is not parsed in external files.

Comment: yes, it is in separate js file. got it. I'll try to initialize a url variable in view & access that in js file. Thanks everyone for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was external js file. Razor engine doesn't work with external js file, thus the url was not correct. It is working if i put the same code in view. Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the other way around: external JS files cannot work with Razor engine (that's quite obvious if you think about it). If you set a javascript variable to @Url.Action('','',) inside a view (= which is covered by the Razor engine), then you can reference this variable in your external script.

Inside a view:

```
<script>
var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("GetCities", "People")';
</script>
```

Inside your external script (assuming the script above is referenced as well):

```
$.ajax({
url: ajaxUrl,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: {'id' : id },
success: function (cities) {
    alert('success');
},
error:function(err, result){
    alert('error');
}
```

});

It's not the best practice (because your external script has a dependency on a variable that might or might not exist).

Comment: so, what are your suggestions to handle this? I can't put all these(if there are many) javascript codes into view.

Comment: If you want to use Razor to generate URIs for you, there's not much else you can do. You could for instance declare a root variable that you can use in your external scripts to create the rest of the path (something like url: rootVariable + 'People/GetCities'), or use some kind of Javascript helper method.